# After displaying the message, want return to first screen

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally

Actually I am showing a chooserDialog and allowing user to select one of the option. And after completing the function displaying the Msg box with "Completed MSg", and after clicking on "OK" want to shows ChooserDialog again

Below is the code for showing msg

```
createFeature: function() {
    var record = Ext.create(this.model, {
        Name: "(Copy of) " + this._newObj.get('Name'),
    });
    record.save({
        callback: function(result, operation) {
            if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('created ' + result.get('PortfolioItemTypeName') + ':', result.get('Name'));
            }
            else{
                console.log("error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are your friend: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-alert

You'll notice that the 3rd argument of the alert() method is an optional callback message that can be executed when the MessageBox is closed. That will be where you want to implement any post-"OK"-click logic.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I am already referring to docs. Still was unable to implement it properly. I will update with my tried code.

Comment: Ok, then what's the problem? Can you update your code based on the callback I mentioned?